# Why does Python `pip.main(['install', ...])` give ImportError, but only for package names with dot?

Tags: python, pip, importerror

When running the following code (Python 2.7.12, on Linux using `sudo -H`), starting with a situation where the packages 'plaitpy' and 'bda.basen' have never been installed,

```py
import sys
import os

# The following code successfully installs bda.basen, then fails to import it.
# However, it works for plaitpy (a random recently updated package).

assert '/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages' in sys.path

import pip
pip.main(['install', 'plaitpy', 'bda.basen'])

assert '/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages' in sys.path

assert os.path.isfile('/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/plaitpy/__init__.py')
import plaitpy # this succeeds, as expected
print plaitpy 

assert os.path.isfile('/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/bda/basen/__init__.py')
import bda.basen # THIS FAILS WITH 'ImportError: No module named bda.basen'
print bda.basen
```

then the last `import` statement fails with `ImportError: No module named bda.basen`.

Based on some experiments, this seems to be happening for every package whose name contains a dot (like `bda.basen` and `ruamel.yaml`), and only for those.

**My question:** Why?  And how to fix this?

Complete runnable code (which will update your system-wide packages!) is at https://gist.github.com/marnix/2f4efc1154547103bcec3783e6015bfc.

Comment: Does `/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/bda/__init__.py` exist?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`bda` is a [namespace package](https://packaging.python.org/guides/packaging-namespace-packages/) and therefore doesn't include `bda/__init__.py`, so there's no way to import that package in Python 2 until you either restart the interpreter or manually call `site.main()`. This is because a `.pth` file is created in your `site-packages` that tells Python that this is a namespace under which other modules reside. All the `.pth` files are loaded by `site.main()` when the interpreter starts up, but since yours was created after, Python doesn't know about it.

```
In [1]: import pip

In [2]: pip.main(['install', 'bda.basen'])
Collecting bda.basen
Requirement already satisfied: setuptools in /usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages (from bda.basen)
Installing collected packages: bda.basen
Successfully installed bda.basen-1.1
Out[2]: 0

In [3]: import bda.basen
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
ImportError                               Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-3-e9d84961fc34> in <module>()
----> 1 import bda.basen

ImportError: No module named bda.basen

In [4]: import site

In [5]: site.main()

In [6]: import bda.basen

In [7]:
```

Python 3.3+ behaves as you'd expect because it natively supports namespace packages and doesn't require you to call `site.main()`.

Comment: Spot-on, and that within 15 minutes of my question... Thanks a lot!